# How do I perform both a read and a write of a boolean in one atomic operation?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a method that gets called by multiple threads

```
public class MultiThreadClass
{
    public void Gogogo()
    {
        // method implementation
    }

    private volatile bool running;
}
```

in Gogogo(), I want to check if `running` is true, and if so, return from the method.  However, if it is false, I want to set it to true and continue the method.  The solution I see is to do the following:

```
public class MultiThreadClass
{
    public void Gogogo()
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            if (this.running)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.running = true;
        }

        // rest of method

        this.running = false;
    }

    private volatile bool running;
    private readonly object locker = new object();
}
```

Is there another way to do this?  I've found out that if I leave out the lock, `running` could be false for 2 different threads, set to true, and the rest of the method would execute on both threads simultaneously.

I guess my goal is to have the rest of my method execute on a single thread (I don't care which one) and not get executed by the other threads, even if all of them (2-4 in this case) call Gogogo() simultaneously.

I could also lock on the entire method, but would the method run slower then?  It needs to run as fast as possible, but part of it on only one thread at a time.

(Details: I have a dicionary of ConcurrentQueue's which contain "results" which have "job names".  I am trying to dequeue one result per key in the dictionary (one result per job name) and call this a "complete result" which is sent by an event to subscribers.  The results are sent via an event to the class, and that event is raised from multiple threads (one per job name; each job raises a "result ready" event on it's own thread)

Comment: Have you looked at `Interlocked`?

Comment: I'd say knowing how to do this is cool.  But, almost certainly micro-optimization.  Definitly micro-optimization if you have not already run code analysis to determine that this code is indeed a bottleneck.  Innocent until proven guilty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` if you change your bool to an int:

```
private volatile int running = 0;

if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) == 0)
{
    //running changed from false to true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Interlocked.Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Interlocked` to handle this case without a `lock`, if you *really* want to:

```
public class MultiThreadClass
{
    public void Gogogo()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref running, 1) == 0)
        {
            //Do stuff

            running = 0;
        }
    }

    private volatile int running = 0;
}
```

That said, unless there is a really high contention rate (which I would not expect) then your code should be entirely adequate.  Using `Interlocked` also suffers a bit in the readability department due to not having `bool` overloads for their methods.

Comment: Thanks Servy.  Why exactly doesn't Interlocked have bool overloads?  It seems they would be useful (that way I don't have to use `1` and `0` to represent true and false).

Comment: @SamPearson Who knows.  They simply didn't take the time to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Monitor class instead of boolean flag. Use Monitor.TryEnter:

```
public void Gogogo()
{
    if Monitor.TryEnter(this.locker)
    { 
         try 
         { 
              // Do stuff
         } 
         finally 
         {
            Monitor.Exit(this.locker); 
         } 
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not causing invocations of this method while another is running to skip the method body, which is what is requested.